# Scrape img src with try/except in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
images = []
    try:
        images = [img["src"] for img in soup.select(".img-lazy")]
    except:
        images = [img["src"] for img in soup.select(".img-thumb")]
    else:
        images = [img["src"] for img in soup.select(".author-bio")]
```

I try to scrape image src from different pages. If works fine only with try and except, but some pages have image in different class name so I add another except condition. It shows error then I add else condition. But now it only scrapes else condition data. I want that first it look for .img-lazy then for .img-thumb and in last for .author-bio class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: You should (almost) **never** use bare `except` clauses like that. Details about this are all over this platform.

In this case, you are shooting yourself in the foot, because you can't know what exception exactly is raised when that `except` is triggered.

Also, with this logic, whenever the code inside the `try` block executes without a problem (thus assigning the `images` variable), the `except` block is skipped and then the `else` block is executed. This results in the `images` variable being re-assigned (i.e. overwritten) in that block.

This is the logic behind `try-except-else` constructs. (You should read up on that.)

If I understand your requirements and the documentation for [`select`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) correctly, you can just do this instead of that whole `try-except` mess:

```py
images = [img["src"] for img in soup.select(".img-lazy,.img-thumb,.author-bio")]
```

That `select` call should return you all elements that match *any* of those class selectors.

However, I would be careful here, unless you know *for certain* that *every* HTML element with any of those classes is in fact an `<img>` (or more specifically, has a `src` attribute). Because if any of them does *not* have `src` attribute, that code will raise a `KeyError` at this point: `img["src"]`

I would suggest being as precise as possible with the selector:

```py
images = [
    img["src"] 
    for img in soup.select(
        "img[src].img-lazy,img[src].img-thumb,img[src].author-bio"
    )
]
```

For example, this `img[src].img-lazy` will only grab `<img>` tags that **have** a `src` attribute *and* the class `img-lazy`.